# How to make a link navigate to another page and also mailto an email?

Tags: html, hyperlink, mailto

I'd like a link where if someone clicks a mailto link they are also shown a different page.

What would the html look like? Currently:

```
<a href="mailto:someone@mail.com">email</a>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You'll probably need JavaScript to redirect the user after clicking the link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Javascript's window.location on the click event of the link

```
<a href="mailto:someone@mail.com" onclick="window.location=another.html">email</a>
```

---

Update:

If you have to stack up lots of code in the onclick event, create a function instead

```
function handleClick() { 
   _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'emails', 'clicked', 'lead']); //first this
   window.open = 'anotherpage.html'; //or window.location for redirection
}
```

HTML

```
<a onclick="handleClick()" href="mailto:someone@mail.com">email.com</a>
```

Comment: thanks. Do I need to specify js or if I cut/paste what you wrote will that be enough to make the link work?

Comment: also, there is in fact already another onclick event attached to the mailto link - can I still use 2? Right now the html actually is: <a onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'emails', 'clicked', 'lead']);" href="mailto:someone@mail.com">email.com</a>